# How can I run the oldest version Eclipse on Windows 11?

Tags: eclipse

How can I run the oldest version Eclipse on Windows 11? The relevant version is 2007.
Download link:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Older_Versions_Of_Eclipse

Old Eclipse not running

[image: 1]

Comment: The Java has to be 32 bit, not 64 bit.

Comment: Actually the oldest version available in the Eclipse Project archive [here](https://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) is version 1.0. For either version you will have to find a 32 bit Java that runs on Windows 11. Why do you want to run such old versions?

Comment: I want to run an old run just for nostalgia. I want to try. Actually I want to use the first version i.e 1.0 version but I don't know how to find it.